# Jquery, how to escape quotes

Tags: jquery, utf-8, escaping

I'm using a simple jquery code that grabs html code form a tag and then puts this content into a form input

```
<td class="name_cat" ><span class="name_cat">It&#039;s a &quot;test&quot; </span> (5)</td>
```

jquery gets the content into `span.name_cat`and returns it as `It's a "test"`.
So when I print this into an input it becomes

```
<input value="It's a "test"" />
```

which as you can imagine will only show as `It's a` , the following double quote will close the value tag.
What's the trick here to keep the original string while not showing utf8 code in the input?

Jquery code

```
            $(".edit_cat").click(function(){

            tr = $(this).parents("tr:first");
            id_cat = $(this).attr("id");
            td_name = tr.find(".name_cat");
            span_name = tr.find("span.name_cat").html();
            form = '<form action="/admin/controllers/edit_cat.php" method="post" >'+
                            '<input type="hidden" name="id_cat" value="'+id_cat+'" />'+
                            '<input type="text" name="name_cat" value="'+span_name+'" />'+
                            '<input type="submit" value="save" />'+
                            '</form>';
            td_name.html(form);

            console.log(span_name);


        }
        );
```

I basically need `html()` not to decode Utf8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build the form the way you are now, but traverse the form object using jQuery's context

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#go').click(function() { 
        var tester = $('<div></div>').html('It&#039;s a &quot;test&quot;');
        var form = $('<form action="/admin/controllers/edit_cat.php" method="post" >' +
                    '<input type="hidden" name="id_cat" />' +
                    '<input type="text" name="name_cat" />' +
                    '<input type="submit" value="save" />' +
                    '</form>');
        $(':hidden:first', form).attr('value', tester.text());
        $(':text:first', form).attr('value', "Some attribute");

        $('#output').append(form);
    });
});
</script>
<input id="go" type="submit" value="click"/>
<div id="output">
</div>
```

What I've done here is wrapped your form html input in a jQuery object as `form`.  Then, you can query items within that object's context using the little-used jQuery form of:

> **jQuery( selector, [context] )**
>   selector: string containing a selector expression
>   context: DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

edit: I created a `tester` object and set the content to your html example.  Then, when I set the value in the hidden input, I call `.text()` to get the non-html representation.  The value is the same as you'd expect.

```
<form action="/admin/controllers/edit_cat.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id_cat" value="It's a &quot;test&quot;">
    <input type="text" name="name_cat" value="Some attribute">
    <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

You'd have to decode this html on the backend, though.  This is probably the best you'd be able to do because XML doesn't allow 'escaping' quotes like `"\"this\""`.  The specification requires quotes to be escaped like `&quot;this&quot;`.

Comment: No problem! I forgot to mention that this is different because jQuery is handling the 'set' operation on 'value' (in a cross-browser manner?).  You can't rely on string concatenation.

Answer (score 12):

I believe this should take care of it for you.

```
var span_name = tr.find("span.name_cat").html().replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/yzthA/

Also, don't forget to declare your variables with `var` if you haven't.

Comment: great input but I was looking for something more general

Answer (score 2):

You can HTML encode the values with this function:

```
function htmlEncode(str) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var txt = document.createTextNode(str);
    div.appendChild(txt);
    return div.innerHTML;
}
```

and then encode any values that can contain quotes:

```
span_name = htmlEncode(tr.find("span.name_cat").html());
```

A better alternative might be to build the inputs with jQuery and set the values with the val() method and then append to the form:

```
var $form = $('<form action="/admin/controllers/edit_cat.php" method="post" />');
var $id_cat_input = $('<input type="hidden" name="id_cat" />');
$id_cat_input.val(id_cat);
$id_cat_input.appendTo($form);
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted user113716's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6475000/1762224) into a jQuery plugin and cleaned it up a bit.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.escapeQuotes = function() {
    return this.html().replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
  }
})(jQuery);

var spanValue = $('span').escapeQuotes();
var formTemplate = [
  '<form action="/admin/controllers/edit_cat.php" method="post" >',
    '<input type="text" name="name_cat" value="' + spanValue + '" />',
    '<input type="submit" value="save" />',
  '</form>'
].join('');

$(formTemplate).appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="name_cat">It&#039;s a &quot;test&quot; </span> (5)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should convert them to html entities or skip them. 
A quote as a html entity looks like this: "
Do it with your programming language. Not with js.

Comment: good solution. convert the quotes to html entities is providing to shown on front end, also. escaping, too.

Comment: ? i don't understand what this has to do with anything. The string I'm grabbing is coming from the html code and it's already converted to html entities.